# Blackberry 10 get device physical storage capacity programmatically

Tags: blackberry-10

How I get Blackberry 10 device total physical storage and available physical storage programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [FileSystemInfo](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__filesysteminfo.html) class.